# GraphQL returning null data from axios

Tags: graphql, axios, express-graphql

I am writing a GraphQL server in Node.js and Express. I have a JSON file of data and so I am using Axios to query data from that JSON file and pass it to GraphQL query,

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
name:'RootQueryType',
fields: {
    holiday: {
        type: Holiday,
        args:{
            date:{type:GraphQLString},
        },
        resolve(parentValue, args) {
            return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/holidays?date='+ args.date).then(res => res.data);
        }
    },
```

On `console.log(res.data)`, I am getting the data, however, on querying by date from GraphiQL, I am getting

`{
  "data": {
    "holiday": {
      "holiday": null
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with the exact same issue sometime back. I realized that the data from the REST API / JSON file take some time to be fetched and GraphQL doesn't wait to receive it. So I decided to use Async and Await, and that way, GraphQL waited for the data to be received. In your case, the code would look like:

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
name:'RootQueryType',
fields: {
    holiday: {
        type: Holiday,
        args:{
            date:{type:GraphQLString},
        },
        Async resolve(parentValue, args) {
            const results= await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/holidays?date='+ args.date)
           .then(res => res.data);
           return results;
        }
    },
```