# GraphiQL returning null values when trying to fetch a particular, single record

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, json-server, graphiql

I am trying to build a basic GraphQL schema. I have a JSON Server that's running on port 3000 that contains the data I want to retrieve using GraphiQL.

Following is the code I've written for the same:

```
const CustomerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name:'Customer',
fields:() => ({
    id: { type:GraphQLString },
    name: { type:GraphQLString }        
})
});


const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
name : 'RootQueryType',
fields:{
    customer : {
        type : CustomerType,
        args:{
            id:{type:GraphQLString}
        },
        resolve(parentValue,args){
            return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/customers/?id='+args.id)
            .then(res => res.data);
        }
    }
}        
});
```

This is how my I'm writing my query.

```
    customer(id : "123"){
          id,
          name
    }
```

And this is the output that is being generated.

```
    {
       "data": {
          "customer": {
              "id": null,
              "name": null,
           }
       }
    }
```

However, when I try to verify whether the right data is being fetched from the data.json file using console.log, the output so generated contains the correct, non-null values. Can someone please help me out with this? Also, there is no error that occurs when I try to fetch the list of all the customers at once, using a GraphQLList, as follows:

```
customers:{
        type: new GraphQLList(CustomerType),
        resolve(parentValue,args){
            return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/customers/')
            .then(res => res.data);
        }
```

Comment: The response from JSON Server is an array of customer objects, not a single object (it just happens to have a length of one). Change your resolver to return `res.data[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel ! Your suggestion along with using async and await (from the following response) have resolved the issue I had!                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589649/graphql-returning-null-data-from-axios